# setting a button value on request scope and getting on other jsp

Tags: jsp

i m trying to set value in request scope and getting it another jsp as i click on button pop window open and getting null value , cause my requirement is getting the value of button on other jsp to validate the two section of code if user on button 1 then `find by id`  text area open and if click on button 2 then `find by name` text area open then that pop window should be closed

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Using Buttons</TITLE>
        <script type="text/javascript">


               function button1()
               {
                var mywindow= window.open("file.jsp", "file","status=1,width=350,height=150");
         }    

        </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Using Buttons</H1>

         <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" name="butto" VALUE="Button 1" ONCLICK="button1()"/>
               <% request.setAttribute("button1" ,"butto");%>

       <% request.setAttribute("button1" ,"butto");%>



    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

and this is my file .jsp

```
<!

DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml"%>
<%@page
    import="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.EmployeeBO"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<%= (String)request.getAttribute("button1") %>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

what is the error in this why i getting null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simple calling window.open() it doesn't transfer your request scope object to other jsp.You cannot send data from request scope to another JSP without using forward();

Example USAGE

```
RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToResource");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

But, in your example it doesn't work by simply calling window.open()

Comment: MuraliPrasanth if i use this in my index.jsp thn it directly forward to file .jsp 
  <%request.setAttribute("button1", "butto"); 
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/file.jsp").forward(request,response);%> i want on the click of button pop will open then value will show through file .jsp

Comment: Instead of using request scope object in your scenario you can simply go for session scope object like you use with request scope object like session.setAttribute() and session.getAttribute()